# Board on top of computer desk drawers blocking 2 cam locks because incorrectly installed upside down. Smashing and removing board cause instability?

Tags: furniture, desk, demolition, drawers

I am disassembling a computer desk for a move.

[image]

I think that removing the cam locks would remove the top of the desk.

The problem is that there's a board on top of the drawers that is blocking 2 cam locks because the board was incorrectly installed upside down a long time ago.

[image]

[image]

The board should look like this (tower side):

[image]

[image]

If I can’t figure out how to continue, will smashing and removing the board on the right side cause instability in my desk?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just **rotating** the cam locks should allow you to remove the top, they don't have to be pulled out to release the cam-lock post on the top.. You could use a thin slotted screwdriver to rotate them even though they are blocked from removal. Then take off the top and when you put it back together make sure you do not make the same mistake.

Comment: The thin slotted screwdriver works on the third picture, which is the right side of the problem side. The thin slotted screwdriver however doesn’t fit on the second picture (left side). I’m scraping at it right now, as the screwdriver won’t fit to rotate. Look for an even smaller thin slotted screwdriver, and keep pulling?

Comment: If you could beg, borrow, or buy a *long handled* thin slotted driver you should be able to get that one on the left. Even if you have to gouge out a bit of material to reveal more of the cam it would be better than destroying the whole board.

Comment: @JeffKang You can also drive the cam with a screwdriver or other flat object stuck in only the lower, exposed part of the slot (off-center) and then tap that the right direction with a hammer.

Comment: I’m still looking for something small to best fit in the exposed Phillips head “rectangle” slots heh. Thanks a lot for the hammer suggestion though.